# Web Bluetooth API Store connection object

Tags: javascript, web-bluetooth

Were successfully tested Web Bluetooth API and it looks to be a good solution for us. But after we have successfully paired against a Bluetooth device and retrieved the gatt server. How do we keep the device as we're not able to serilize it to local storage? If we refresh the site we dont want to do the whole request device-thing again to be able to connect. I guess it should be possible to just do a connect again if we have the device saved somewhere.

Thanks
Anders

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to persist a Bluetooth LE connection on browser refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45467214/is-it-possible-to-persist-a-bluetooth-le-connection-on-browser-refresh)

Answer (score -2):

If refresh is all you care, you can use the following function to show an alert to users before the refresh:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  return "Are you sure you want to refresh?";
}
```

If the website is not complicated you can consider using Ajax for requests instead on navigating in other pages.