# Is it possible to persist a Bluetooth LE connection on browser refresh

Tags: web-bluetooth

Is it possible to persist a Bluetooth LE connection on browser refresh? Or at least minimize the pairing time?

Comment: I didn't even know you could use Bluetooth for web development, but is it possible to save some aspect of the connection to Local Storage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually navigator.permissions.query would support this. Sample code from [Web Bluetooth Specification](https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/#example-permission-api-query)

```js
navigator.permissions.query({
  name: "bluetooth",
  deviceId: sessionStorage.lastDevice,
}).then(result => {
  if (result.devices.length == 1) {
    return result.devices[0];
  } else {
    throw new DOMException("Lost permission", "NotFoundError");
  }
}).then(...);
```

However, [no browser currently implements this](https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/web-bluetooth/blob/gh-pages/implementation-status.md).

As of [Q3 2017](https://www.chromium.org/teams/device-team/device-okrs) the chromium implementation is actively working on Web Bluetooth but not this feature.

Comment: Can I filter list with device id?

Answer (score 3):

I recently implemented a new permissions backend as well as two APIs that will enable previously permitted Bluetooth devices to be used.

The new permissions backend is implemented behind the chrome://flags/#enable-web-bluetooth-new-permissions-backend. The new backend will persist device permissions granted through [`requestDevice()`](https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/#dom-bluetooth-requestdevice) until the permission is reset in Site Settings or the Page Info dialog box.

The [`getDevices()`](https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/#dom-bluetooth-getdevices) and [`watchAdvertisements()`](https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/#dom-bluetoothdevice-watchadvertisements) are implemented behind the chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features flag for Chrome 85.0.4165.0 or greater. The recommended use of these APIs is to use `getDevices()` to retrieve an array of permitted BluetoothDevices and then calling `watchAdvertisements()` on these devices to start a scan. When advertisement packets are detected from the devices, the [`advertisementreceived`](https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/#eventdef-bluetoothdevice-advertisementreceived) Event will be fired on the device that it corresponds to. At this point, the Bluetooth device is in range and can be connected to.

Please give this new feature a try, and file any bugs at https://crbug.com using the Blink>Bluetooth component.

Comment: If interested in getDevices() and persistent connections get activ in this crbug thread: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1173186&can=1&q=advertisementreceived%20component%3ABlink%3EBluetooth

Comment: @Ovidio Is there any update in 2024 chrome 122? Are these still behind enable-experimental-web-platform-features flag and are they likely to remain that way. I ask because without enabling the flags `getDevices` is `undefined` on Windows.

Comment: If, like me, you want this to be available and not behind an experimental flag, please see https://issues.chromium.org/issues/40452449 and add your vote to it.